# Download a zip archive of (empty or not) xml and svg files blocked by Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to download a zip archive of xml and svg files placed in separate folders:

```
+archive.zip
   +imgs
       test.svg
       test1.svg
       test2.svg
   +xml
       highway.xml
```

If I put more than three svg files in the imgs folder (even with empty svg and xml files), Chrome detect the archive as malicious file.

I tested with Chrome 48 and 49 (my current Chrome version is 49.0.2623.87 m).
I've no problems with Firefox 44 and IE 10.

Here is my simple html page (read and download file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="readAndDownloadButton" type="button" onclick="toggleSelectFileInput()" class="clickable">readAndDownloadButton</button>

        <input id="zippedConfigFileInput"
               type="file"
               name="zippedConfigFile" 
               style="display: none" 
               onchange="readAndDownloadFile()"
               accept="application/zip" />

        <script>
            function toggleSelectFileInput() {
                var inputSelect = document.getElementById('zippedConfigFileInput');
                inputSelect.click();
            }

            function readAndDownloadFile() {
                var inputElement = document.getElementById('zippedConfigFileInput');
                var file = inputElement.files[0];

                var fr = new FileReader();

                fr.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
                    var resultStr = fr.result;

                    downloadFile(file.name, resultStr);
                });

                fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            }


            function downloadFile(name, uri) {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.download = name;
                link.href = uri;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I've tested this page served by a Glassfish 4.1 server localy, and then by reading directly the html file (with no server) giving the same effect.

I don't understand why Chrome is detecting this archive as a malicious file!

If I remove the xml folder or one svg file, download work as expected.

---

**UPDATE:**
I did some more tests and it appears that Chrome don't want to download the result of FileReader.readAsDataURL for some files.

I did a new test page with only one link  and as href the result of the zip archive (with empty svg and xml files) given by FileReader.readAsDataURL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="data:application/x-zip-compressed;base64,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">Download</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

This gives the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity...
That was effectively a bug from chrome.

I opened a post directly on https://bugs.chromium.org.

Here is the last mail of one of the chrome's devs:

> We will re-evaluate the campaign rule on our side to see if it is worth keeping.

Since Chrome version 51.0.2704.103 m, the bug disappeared.